# How to Update VS2019 to a version other than latest?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

On March 09, 2021 Microsoft released VS2019 16.8.7 and 16.9.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.8#16.8.7
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.9.1

I have currently installed 16.8.6 and would like to upgrade to 16.8.7, but the installer only offers the upgrade to 16.9.1!

How can I upgrade to 16.8.7 ?

Comment: See [Update Visual Studio while on a servicing baseline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-servicing-baseline?view=vs-2019). Should work for 16.8.7 too, though 16.8.x is technically not a "*servicing baseline*".

Comment: So I need a bootstrapper for 16.8, but "my.visualstudio.com" offers only 16.0, 16.4, 16.7 and 16.9 :(

Comment: Have you tried the 16.8.x ones on the linked page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers).

Comment: Thank you! Will try. Strange that 16.8.7 is not listed there, while 16.9.1 already is.

Comment: I created an offline installation using the 16.8.6 bootstrapper from the link you provided and installed it on a computer that had 16.8.3.
Result is that the computer now has 16.8.6 installed and it now offers only update to 16.9.1.
So I guess you really would need a bootstrapper for 16.8.7, but Microsoft did not provide one. I guess this is because 16.8 is not a "support baseline.
But why do they post release notes for 16.8.7, when they don't offer an installer for it?

Comment: That looks to be the case, [indeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-servicing-baseline?view=vs-2019#how-to-stay-on-a-servicing-baseline): "*When an update* ***for a servicing baseline*** *is available, fixed-version bootstrapper files are made available ...*". Guess it's one more reason to stay on servicing baselines.

Comment: P.S. Well, well... 16.8.7 shows up today on that [same page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Just use that link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers

There you can choose specific installer for any version VS 2019 as you want .